# How can I convert stateless function to class component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-component

I am new in react native, I have been looking for how to convert this function to a class component in react native. Please I need help to convert the code below to react component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

export default ({captures=[]}) => (
    <ScrollView 
        horizontal={true}
        style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]} 
    >
        {captures.map(({ uri }) => (
            <View style={styles.galleryImageContainer} key={uri}>
                <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImage} />
            </View>
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? This seems like a component with only a render. And why convert it?

Comment: It already is a component, specifically a function component. Are you wanting to convert it into a class component instead?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert it to class component instead

Comment: Do you know how to create a class component? May you show your attempt at converting this function component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn this into a class component, just move the code into the class component's render method, and change references to `props` with references to `this.props`. For this component, no other changes are needed.

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { captures = [] } = this.props;
    return (
      <ScrollView 
        horizontal={true}
        style={[styles.bottomToolbar, styles.galleryContainer]} 
      >
        {captures.map(({ uri }) => (
          <View style={styles.galleryImageContainer} key={uri}>
            <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.galleryImage} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```